# Axios Post request Giving Error 400 , Bad Request

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am using the Hackerrank API for a Project. 
See the official documentation, click [here](https://rapidapi.com/hackerrank/api/hackerrank)!

There is an example on their website which uses UNIREST,

```
unirest.post("https://hackerrank-hackerrank.p.rapidapi.com/https://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json")
.header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "hackerrank-hackerrank.p.rapidapi.com")
.header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "a72a0f1b5dmshdc3f55e233876eap1b8939jsnffad2a5b6e6e")
.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.send("callback_url=https://mywebsite.com/responseHandler")
.send("source=puts 'Hello World'")
.send("lang=8")
.send("testcases=["This is input 1", "This is input 2"]")
.send("wait=false")
.send("format=json")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
});
```

Since I am using axios, I converted it to an equivalent axios code which looks like:

```
var params =  {
            "callback_url": "https://mywebsite.com/responseHandler",
            "source": "puts 'Hello World'",
            "lang": 8,
            "testcases": "[\"This is input 1\", \"This is input 2\"]",
            "wait": false,
            "format": "json"
          }
        var config = {
            mode: "no-cors",
            headers: {
                "X-RapidAPI-Host": "hackerrank-hackerrank.p.rapidapi.com",
                "X-RapidAPI-Key": "a72a0f1b5dmshdc3f55e233876eap1b8939jsnffad2a5b6e6e",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        }
        axios.post("https://hackerrank-hackerrank.p.rapidapi.com/https://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json", params, config)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
```

I expect this to work just the example shown in the example, but it gives me the following error:

> Request failed with status code 400
>   Error: Request failed with status code 400
>      at createError (createError.js:16)
>      at settle (settle.js:18)
>      at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)

I am relatively new to this, if someone can point out what i am doing wrong, that would be very helpful!

Comment: The precise Error being:

Answer (score 3):

As request `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should pass data as [FromData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

```
var data= new FormData(); // Currently empty
data.append('callback_url', 'https://mywebsite.com/responseHandler');
data.append('source', "puts 'Hello World'");
data.append('lang', '8');
data.append('testcases', "[\"This is input 1\", \"This is input 2\"]");
data.append('wait', false);
data.append('format', "json");
data.append('api_key', "<valid hackerrenk api key>"); // API KEY is mandatory

axios.post("https://hackerrank-hackerrank.p.rapidapi.com/https://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json", data, config)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
```

Comment: If you check the response, it is showing `api_key: "The API key field is required.` You need to add `data.append('api_key', '<valid hacker rank api key>')`

Comment: This worked for me... and I tried a lot of options prior to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ashish pointed me into the correct direction, but with `FormData()` I received a status 415 (Unsupported Media Type) instead of the status 400.

What worked for me was using `URLSearchParams()` instead of `FormData()`, [like in this example](https://gist.github.com/akexorcist/ea93ee47d39cf94e77802bc39c46589b):

```
var data= new URLSearchParams(); // Currently empty
data.append('callback_url', 'https://mywebsite.com/responseHandler');
data.append('source', "puts 'Hello World'");
data.append('lang', '8');
data.append('testcases', "[\"This is input 1\", \"This is input 2\"]");
data.append('wait', false);
data.append('format', "json");
data.append('api_key', "<valid hackerrenk api key>"); // API KEY is mandatory

axios.post("https://hackerrank-hackerrank.p.rapidapi.com/https://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json", data, config)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
```

(I had a different example with a different URL, but can't share my example since it's an URL from my company)